# How to convert a xlsx file to a text file so that text file to get the exact structure in the text file and how to manage the mergerd cells

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working with a xlsx file which  have structure and i have to exactly copy the structure to the text file.My code is  copying all the data from the xlsx file and pasting them into the txt file, but the structure is not right at all.I am giving the complete code as well as the xlsx file

[image]

And the code i am using is

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("D:\\data.txt", "UTF-8");
    try {

        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\resources\\BLF_20170111_BDPM_C.xlsx"));

        //Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (file);

        //Get first sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);


        //Iterate through each rows from first sheet
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            //For each row, iterate through each columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                switch(cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                        writer.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                        writer.println(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t"); // here i am writing the data to the text file.
                        writer.println(cell.getStringCellValue()+ "\t\t");
                        break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        file.close();
        FileOutputStream out = 
            new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\writedatasamp.txt"));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        writer.close();
    }

}

}
```

But the problem is the data is coming

Sponsorship
Part of a Merged Cell
Part of a Merged Cell
Part of a Merged Cell
Part of a Merged Cell
Part of a Merged Cell
Part of a Merged Cell
Part of a Merged Cell
Part of a Merged Cell
Part of a Merged Cell
Part of a Merged Cell
HJL
Post Priviledge
Counting starts from 01-01-2018 to 30-11-2018
Starting  date 16-Jan-2019
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name4
Name5
Name6
Part of a Merged Cell
Name7
Part of a Merged Cell
Name8
Name9
loc. ccy
admin. ccy
loc. ccy
admin. ccy
admin. ccy
admin. ccy
India (1.2%)
ARC 56
INR
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
ARC 57
INR
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
ARC 58
INR
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0

So can i get the same structute as the xlsx file ? and more over in the sponsorship row other cells are merged so its giving a message i.e  Part of a Merged Cell. How i can solve this problem?

Comment: You're using `PrintWriter#println`

Comment: I have also used print but then it's also not coming desired way

Comment: @ifly6 can you edit my code i have already tried